# React How to transfer date from input to other component?

Tags: reactjs, date, input

I'm new to React and my problem is I need to transfer date from input to other component, I have this:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import Components from '../../components';

  const Kalendarz = () =>{
        const {Data} = Components;
        const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date());
        return (
          <div>
            <Data date={date} />
            <input 
               name='date' 
               type='date' 
               value={date} 
               onChange={(e) => setDate(e.target.value)}
               />
           </div>
    }

  export default Kalendarz;


const Data = ({date}) => {
    // Why 'date' is undefined????
    console.log(date) 
    return(
        <div>
            <h2>Your date: {date}</h2>
        </div>
    );
}
export default Data;
```

I need to show chosen date in this h2 but it's not working and I don't know were is problem, all the time date in component Data is undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date());
  return (
    <div>
      <Data date={date} />
      <input
        name="date"
        type="date"
        value={date}
        onChange={(e) => setDate(e.target.value)}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;

const Data = ({ date }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Your date: {date.toString()}</h2>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Still date in component Data is undefined :/

Comment: This code works on my PC. Have you changed something ?

Comment: No I didn't change nothing, no my PC all the time show date is undefinied :/

Comment: can you copy all of your code to question ?

Comment: done, I can't add toString() to date because date is undefined

Comment: Maybe try to import `Data` like so: import Data from '../../components/Data'.  And remove string `const {Data} = Components;`   
`data` without `toString()` will throw error

Comment: Cool! You are welcome. Please mark answer as correct, thank you.